# How to translate blocks content (created with views module) in drupal 6?

Tags: 6, i18n-l10n

I created blocks with views, my question is this: When you select a language, even the block content ( created with views )applies to me translated ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a filter to your view, under the `Node translation` group that will make your view filter out nodes that don't belong in the default or current language.

[image: Views filter, node translation group]

**Edit** You may need the [i18n views module](http://drupal.org/project/i18nviews) to see some of the options in the screenshot.